# Label not replaced with correct value in prototype from sonata admin bundle collection field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

My collection is made of this type

```
<?php
namespace Gustaw\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AttributeValueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('value')
         ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Gustaw\AdminBundle\Entity\AttributeValue',
                'label' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'attribute_value_type';
    }
}
```

And this is my form

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper->with('General')
            ->add('name', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'fields' => array(
                        'name' => array()
                    )
                ))
            ->add('custom', null, array(
                    'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => 'GustawAdminBundle:Category',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->orderBy('c.root', 'ASC')
                                ->addOrderBy('c.lft', 'ASC');
                    },))
            ->end()
            ->with('Values')
            //->add('values', 'sonata_type_collection')
            ->add('notcustomvalues', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new AttributeValueType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
            ))
        ->end();
}
```

Problem is when adding new elements to collection. Each single AttributeValueType gets a label "__name__label__ *" when I don't want to have any label for this field as I set it to false.

I tried setting "prototype_name" hoping it will change something just to make it worse.

The only ideas that came to my mind are:

1st - create custom theme without label just for this one collection
2nd - edit base.js in SonataAdminBundle

2nd obviously is not really good option so I am left just with the first one.

Question is: Are there any other options I have?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:  'options' => array(label => 'Some Label');

Like this:

```
        ->add('notcustomvalues', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AttributeValueType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Some Label'
                ),

        ))
```